# Lenovo beeps once and shows an error screen at start up

Tags: boot, bios, troubleshooting, lenovo-laptop

I need some help trouble shooting my wife's laptop. When I try to start it the laptop emits one beep and shows this screen.

[image: Error screen]

I've checked Lenovos basic beep codes [here](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/migr-46018-kr) and that doesn't seem to match this problem.

The screen comes up so probably not the graphics card misbehaving.

The screen itself says the ram is OK. Not sure if that can be trusted.

Could this be the hard drive? It's solid-state but its only 2 years old so that seems a bit soon.

Thoughts?

Comment: What happens when you "Press any Key to Exit"?

Comment: Nothing. It is either frozen at that point or unable to continue.